# Minimum length (bits) of instructions? Assembly, Mips

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I am studying for my midterm exam and I try to solve a question below.

> In a certain processor’s instruction set, there are 31 instructions,
>   and 128 registers in the register file. What will be the minimum
>   length (in bits) of instructions and why?

My assumption is in the default Mips have 2^5=32 register, so we will have 2^7 =128 register. It is 7 bits and 31 instruction = 31+1 = 32 bits. So if I say 7+32=39 bits is the minimum length of instruction?

Is this correct assumption?

Comment: 31 instructions can be encoded with 5 bits. As for the minimal length, I'd say it is 5 bits. The only ones necessary to encode the instruction opcode. It is nowhere written that say, those instructions are not using the registers implicitly, pretty much like the Java bytecode does with the stack.

Comment: Minimum length would be 5 bits, for up to 32 instructions, since there is usually at least one instruction that takes no register operands (e.g. NOP, HALT, RET, etc). For one register operand you would need 5+7 = 12 bits, for two operands, 5+7+7 = 19 bits, etc. Also for instructions needing an immediate operand you might need a much longer instruction.

Comment: How does the `It is 7 bits and 31 instruction = 31+1 = 32 bits` part work?

Comment: @dtech i thought [0-31] so it should be 31+1=32.

Comment: There is no correct answer because the number of bits per instruction could be variable. Think Huffman coding.